# How to check my permissions in JIRA?

Tags: jira

In order to edit version numbers for a project in JIRA, I need 'project admin' permission.

How can I check if I have this permission?  Can I get a list of my project permissions?

(I can see the list of groups I belong to on my user profile, but not the permissions associated with any group)

EDIT:
According to the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions) it is the permission "Administer Projects" needed to edit project versions.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a "project admin" permission in JIRA. I would recommend you check the [JIRA documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/dosearchsite.action?queryString=permissions&startIndex=0&where=JIRA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to check if someone has a certain permissions.
The easiest one is to use the *JIRA admin helper* functionality available within JIRA as of version 6 (see [Troubleshooting permissions with the JIRA admin helper](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Global+Permissions#ManagingGlobalPermissions-TroubleshootingpermissionswiththeJIRAadminhelper)), and as a [freely available add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-admin-helper-plugin) from Atlassian Labs for JIRA 5.0 - 5.2.11.

Within JIRA 6 (or JIRA 5 after installing the add-on), go to the JIRA administration, and find the admin helper. It's pretty self explanatory. It lets you check whether you can do certain operations on a project, and tells you why, or why not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, quite helpful! The _JIRA admin helper_ functionality is built into JIRA as of version 6 only apparently, but available as a freely available add-on for JIRA 5 - I have adjusted your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The smart guys from [Kepler-Rominfo](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/vendors/36224) provide a dedicated (commercial) Add-on for that purpose, see [RightsDNA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.keplerrominfo.jira.plugins.rightsdna):

> Ever wondered where permissions came from? Ever wondered who can access a certain issue? RightsDNA can answer many of your questions, giving advices for clean security schemes inside your JIRA.
>
> [...] it maintains the sanity of your permission schemes by calculating effective rights of the users and helps you establish a uniform set of permissions for your users.

Please note that I haven't tested this particular add-on myself so far, just took note due to them providing other very sophisticated add-ons I'm interested in and evaluating accordingly.